# Specflow: Same Scenarios with Different Configurable Steps

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I have a feature and was looking for a way to execute it different per environment.  Like I might have an environment where I test things locally and another that hits remote servers.  Using scoped bindings I can accomplish this but it requires duplicating the scenarios and then applying a tag to each scenario.

Eg:

```
@test
Scenario: User can login
    When a user provides valid credentials
    Then they are logged in

@stage
Scenario: User can login
    When a user provides valid credentials
    Then they are logged in
```

Is instead there a way where the scenario is only listed once in the feature and then I have some kind of global tag that would allow the proper filtering of step definitions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I confirm - our objectives are: (1) One definition of a/each scenario (2) Ability to run the same scenario under different environments.

What are you using to set up and execute your test runs?  Do you care if a single test run applies entirely to one environment, or do you want to test both environments in a single run of all unit tests?

Comment: a single run would hit entire test suite under one environment.  I don't need to mix/match.  The idea is being I would decide which environment I want to test, set some kinda config, and then run the suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what the .net configuration infrastructure is for.  it's not really specflow specific.  your code should read different configuration settings and you should have the right configuration files for given environments.  i would do this in the same way you do your configuration for moving your application code through different environments.